# Installing ubuntu without any OS

Tags: 12.04, unity, boot, gnome

Is it possible to install ubuntu without having a operating system?
I have tried to install through usb and do not have access to dvd/cd at the moment.
can anyone help?

i got the following error codes:

SQUASHFS error: squash_read_data failed to read block 0x6b56569

the SQUASHFS error: unable to read fragment cache entry unabble to readpage; block 6b56569, size d607

FAT-FS (sdb1):unable to read: node for block updating(i_pos 262162)

i am booting it on Toshiba Satellite L855D-S5220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to install it without having a current OS by booting the Live CD from a USB flash drive.  Use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) on a working computer to load the Live CD into the USB drive.  First run without installing to test out the OS.

Comment: thank you for that. it got it working along with @Radagasp my flash drive was old and wore out

Answer (score 1):

If you have followed instructions carefully, you should have no problem installing from a flash disk. Did you perhaps get information from any place other than an official source?

If so, try this please: [Installation from USB Stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick).

You haven't really supplied us with enough information about what went wrong, so it is difficult to help you. Only two things spring to mind right now:

1. You must have sufficient memory on the flash disk when burning an image.
2. Did you change your boot settings in the BIOS?

Comment: well it was installing. yes i had changed my boot setting. i fell asleep while it was installing and woke up to a page with several SQAUSHFS error codes.

Comment: Ubuntu has a great wiki page dedicated to SQUASHFS errors - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SquashfsErrors - it is most likely that your flashdisk is old/corrupted etc.